# Is there any way to lock a mutex and have it automatically unlock after a given time?

Tags: c, linux, posix, real-time, mutex

This is on Linux but ideally I'd like a POSIX compliant solution.

I have two threads each of which is able to write to a hardware bus via an API function. Only one thread is allowed to write to the bus at any given time, and after a bus write, the bus must not be written to for a given time of the order of several hundred milliseconds.

Both threads are implemented as state machines.

The obvious solution is to use a mutex to serialise access to the bus, set a counter or timestamp, and have the state machine unlock the mutex after the appropriate time has expired.

This seems a little fragile to me. If a future maintenance developer incorrectly modifies the state machine, the mutex might not get released, causing hard-to-diagnose deadlocks.

Is there an API call that locks a mutex, but automatically unlocks it after a given timeout? Google reveals pthread_mutex_timedlock(), but this isn't quite the same thing.

Comment: Set a timer that unlocks the mutex upon expiration.

Comment: @mah: you can't call `pthread_mutex_unlock` from a signal handler though, can you? So what kind of timer are we talking about, and when will it get a chance to run in the context of the thread that holds the lock? Linux does at least have `SIGEV_THREAD_ID`, which gets you a signal in the correct thread that you can use to set a flag to tell the thread to release the mutex. But the thread will have to periodically check the flag.

Comment: @SteveJessop I don't see a clear indication in pthread_mutex_unlock's man page that it cannot be used within a signal handler though what I see there could be ambiguous -- suggesting that after handling the signal the thread shall resume waiting for the mutex as if the signal had not happened. I don't know if that means that even though the mutex has been unlocked, the thread will not notice (though I hope not!). I suppose a really ugly way to deal with that would be for the signal handler to start a new thread with the sole purpose of unlocking the mutex.

Comment: @mah: there doesn't need to be a clear indication in the individual function definition, Posix provides a list of async-signal-safe functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of any pthreads API which allows locks to be automatically released.

Personally I'd try and serialise access to the bus through a single thread to avoid these complications. If that thread maintains an input queue and other threads post their requests to it, then it could do whatever serialisation and conflict resolution it wished, and this also makes it easier to implement the delay before further access. As long as you're careful not to use any blocking functions in this thread your only real failure case is that it might be terminated accidentally.

If you need to both read and write from the bus, you can give every thread an input queue and have worker threads post a "read request" to the IO thread and then wait for the response to be posted back to its own input queue. If there's only ever one outstanding request for a thread then you don't really need a queue, a simple [condition variable](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConditionVariables) and a pointer to the structure to fill in would probably work fine.

If you definitely want two threads to share the resource then I think you're always going to have a risk of the mutex becoming locked up. Even if you set a timer and forcibly release the mutex after a fixed time, that could simply cause different bugs where a thread goes on to use the resource believing it has the lock when in fact it's held by another thread entirely. Ultimately you're trying to plan robustness against future programming errors, which is a fine aim but there's a limit - mutexes are just something one has to be careful with.

I suggest your best approach, if you must go the mutex route, is to simply minimise the code which requires the mutex and avoid blocking calls within it. If you're implementing a state machine, try to ensure that the mutex doesn't have to stay locked between state transitions. If at all possible, scope your mutex locks so that they're only held for the duration of a single function call at some level in your call chain - this makes it a lot easier to spot lock/unlock mismatches by eye. If you're using C++ then use [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) to make releasing your locks more reliable.

But once again, I think you'll find life a lot easier serialising your requests in some way, typically by declaring one thread the arbiter (either one of the existing threads or a new one).

Comment: That seems good to me. A bus access thread seems like the simplest solution to me, in the absence of a time-limited mutex. And it's POSIX compliant.

Comment: Indeed. Often the simplest solution to reason about will yield the fewest bugs! If you're concerned about contention for the bus thread queue, you could try using lock-free queues (such as those in [liblfds](http://www.liblfds.org/)), but it sounds to me that the overhead of a mutex protecting the bus thread queue isn't going to be a big deal, and lock-free implementations can be complex and/or buggy. You can also use callback functions to receive the results of reads if you don't want to block, but callbacks from another thread can become slightly fiddly if you're not careful.

Comment: @SimonElliott: I agree with Cartroo's design. The bus queue locking overhead is neglible. You can avoid the callback issues by having the caller specify a pointer to a semaphore (`sem_t *`) and a pointer where the results are saved. The bus access thread will save the result and `sem_post()` the semaphore when the operation completes. The caller can then either `sem_wait()` or `sem_timedwait()` on the semaphore to wait for the result, or poll with `sem_trywait(). See `man sem_init`, `man sem_post`, and `man sem_wait` (at http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/dir_all_alphabetic.html).

Comment: Semaphores would work fine. I mentioned condition variables in my original answer because I find them slightly more intuitive for "events" like this, whereas I think of semaphores as a natural extension of mutexes for resources which support multiple, but limited, clients. Certainly they can both be used here so I suppose it's primarily just a matter of preference.

Answer (score 1):

How about having a timestamp of last bus access in shared (and mutex-covered) memory? Each write would than look like this:

1. lock mutex
2. check timestamp of last access; if your wait-time has not passed yet, sleep for remainder of this time, as you cannot do anything else in this thread anyway
3. do the write
4. update timestamp of last access
5. unlock mutex

Comment: +1, although there's one potential difference from what the questioner asks for. In this code, whatever thread comes along first during the timeout period gets the lock. If the mutex were only released when time expires, then at that time the highest-priority waiter would get the lock. If all contesting threads have equal priority then this isn't a difference, and anyway you can tinker with this code to get a closer approximation to what was requested.

Answer (score 1):

If faced with this issue, I would probably use another 'APIwrite' thread to interact with the driver.  This thread would loop around a producer-consumer queue pop and a Sleep(several hundred milliseconds).  Any other thread wishing to write just queues up a *writeBuffer.  The writeBuffer struct could contain a function(*writeBuffer) pointer that the APIwrite thread wil call after writing.  This function, provided by the originating thread, could either
signal some event that the originating thread is waiting on on or could just free the *writeBuffer.

Saves messing around with explicit mutexes, timers,  etc and allows sync or async writes.